# Sorting in a matrix SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I try to sort the machine number ascending. If I took out the Prduct description then the machines are sorted ascending. I would like to show the Product description for every machine and I would like to show the machines sorted(M101,M102,M103...)

[image]

```
where Date BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime
    and Name in ('M101','M102','M103','M104','M105','M106','M107','M108','M109','M110', 'M111') 
    group by Date, Name, ProductName

    ) as s

order by Name asc
```

It should look like this here:

[image]

[image]
I did used a matrix

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: can you post group pane image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try these 2 solution

first use case when in ORDER BY clause like this

```
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN name = 'M101' THEN 1 
        WHEN name = 'M102' THEN 2
    END
```

It's not best solution but it's can solved your problem  and second solution is use substring in order by clause like this

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(name,2,10) AS INT)
```

And if you use Column group for dynamic expand column don't forget delete delete sorting condition.
Hope it's help

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately it not works

Comment: Can you post Design View you report ? in first image look like you have 2 level group (Product and Machine number)

Comment: yes thats right, the product description from each machine

Comment: if you want to sorting with machine number I think you'll not group by Product. Result will show look like on second image you post

Comment: but if I exclude Product from group by clause then there is a failure: '...ProductName is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate funtion or the GROUP BY clause'

Comment: Sorry I said not clear. I mean you must delete Product group On report Group pane Not on your query. So in report group you will have only 1 group is "Machine Number group"

Comment: thank you so much, now it shows me the machines sorted :)